# Modeling circular depedencies

Tags: java, data-modeling

I am trying to model down the relationship between student and course. Below are the 2 high level queries i need to support down :

- Finding all the courses a student is enrolled in
- Find all the students enrolled for a course.

The relationship is a M:N relation ship (many to many, i.e. multiple students enroll to multiple courses).

How can i model them in terms of java objects. Intuitively, Student and Course seem to refer each other, creating circular dependency (or back reference).

```
class Student{ 
 Long id
 String name
 List<Course> enrolledCourses;
 Long rollNumber
}

Course{
 Long id
 String name
 List<Student> enrolledStudents;
}
```

Is it the right behaviour to model such requirements in the above manner.

I am a little hesitant to create such circular dependencies, but not sure how i can model it otherwise.

- Is above the right approach ?
- Or does there exist a better way to model these sort of behaviour's ?

Comment: What data modeling method/textbook are you using/following?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're a bit afraid of the redundancy. If Student X visits Course Y, you have Course Y in the student's list of courses and Student X in the course's list of students.

If you pay attention to the modifying methods, this will probably be the best way to model this situation.
But if your fear of ending up with a student visiting a course he wasn't in (according to the course), you'll have to do it like in relational databases and create a relation object.

Now if you think a little more about the situation, there's probably a lot to tell about this course-visit. When did the student visit the course? Did he do any exams? what were the results? Which professor lead this instance of the course? After analysing that, you'll have a much better picture of the situation.

My approach is usually to analyse the situation thoroughly first. Then I analyse my operations on the data. Finally I start thinking about an optimal representation of my data.

Answer (score 0):

This is without problems in Java, and the right approach. A bijective relation, being regularly used in both directions. In JPA they would typically get an annotation to fetch them lazily.

In fact modeling with JPA annotations would allow you to express primary key, many-to-one and such.

I personally would prefer `long rollNumber` instead of the nullable `Long rollNumber`.

Of course not always a sensible thing to do, especially when the entities are subordinate.